# swift 3: Get rtf formatted text from MySQL

Tags: php, nsurlsession, rtf

In my App I have a lot of rtf files that I read and put the text into a `UITextView` with `AttributedText`.

Now I want to put all those files into a MySQL database and read them with a PHP file and `URLSession`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    var returnString = ""
    var aOverskrifter:NSMutableArray = []
    var aLilleTekster:NSMutableArray = []
    var aLangTekster:NSMutableArray = []
    var styledText = NSMutableAttributedString()


    @IBOutlet var txtWikiTekst: UITextView!

    //** Button to get data from php file
    @IBAction func btnHentWiki_Click(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //** Læs fra nettet
        let myURLString = "xxxx.php"

        HentResponseString(url: myURLString)

    }

    //** Show rtf text in UITextView
    @IBAction func btnVisData_Click(_ sender: UIButton) {

        txtWikiTekst.attributedText = styledText
    }

    //** Function the gets the text from php page
    func HentResponseString(url: String) {

        let url = URL(string: url)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("request failed \(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

            //** Bearbejd responseString
            let lines = responseString?.components(separatedBy: "#")

            for line in lines! {

                let fields = line.components(separatedBy: "$")

                var xcounter:Int = 0

                for field in fields {

                    //** Overskrift
                    if xcounter == 0 {
                        self.aOverskrifter.add(field)
                    }
                    //** Lille tekst
                    if xcounter == 1 {
                        self.aLilleTekster.add(field)
                    }
                    //** Lang tekst
                    if xcounter == 2 {
                        self.aLangTekster.add(field)
                        styledText = field
                    }

                    xcounter+=1
                }
            }            
        }
        task.resume()

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But when I run this code I only see the rtf text in the `UITextView` and not the formatted text.

In the database I'm using UTF8 and in the PHP file i use UTF8, but it does not work correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix this or can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code?

Comment: Code updated now.

Comment: If I read from the database and create a new file ind the document directory I can fill the new file with the formatted text. But I cannot read the content of this new file into my textview with the right formatting. If I copy a rtf file into my bundle I can read it without any trouble and it is showed correctly. So why can't I do the same with a file in the document directory?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the RTF text you should convert it to a `Data` object, and use the `Data` object to initialize your `NSAttributedString` variable. To demonstrate this I created an RTF "Hello, world" document in TextEdit, with "Hello" in red text and "world" in blue. The following code, which you can run in a playground, creates that colored attributed string from the contents of the saved TextEdit .rtf file:

```
let rtfText = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf760\n{\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Helvetica;}\n{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;}\n{\\*\\expandedcolortbl;;\\csgenericrgb\\c100000\\c0\\c0;\\csgenericrgb\\c0\\c0\\c100000;}\n\\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww12600\\viewh7800\\viewkind0\n\\pard\\tx720\\tx1440\\tx2160\\tx2880\\tx3600\\tx4320\\tx5040\\tx5760\\tx6480\\tx7200\\tx7920\\tx8640\\pardirnatural\\partightenfactor0\n\n\\f0\\fs24 \\cf2 Hello\\cf0 , \\cf3 world}"

let rtfData = rtfText.data(using: .utf8)!
let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data:rtfData, options: [:], documentAttributes: nil)
```